# Modifying Map via Monocle

Tags: scala, monocle-scala

I wanted to try lenses and the Monocle library seemed (from my noobish perspective) good with all those fancy boilerplate-less `@Lenses`. Unfortunately I found out there are little to non learning materials for beginners (I know basics of FP in vanilla Scala, no Scalaz). Official tutorial lacks easy examples (and/or their results) and mixes in quite complex Scalaz library. One would assume that such trivial task like accessing a Map would be covered on a first page.

I have following snippet:

```
  @Lenses case class House(presentsDelivered: Int)

  type Houses = Map[(Int, Int), House]

  @Lenses case class Town(houses: Houses)

  @Lenses case class Santa(x: Int, y: Int)

  @Lenses case class World(santa: Santa, town: Town)
```

I saw `at` and `index`, but no simple examples (just some weird [magic for me] answer with `applyOptional` which required boilerplate). I want to update the map - `houses` in `Town`. I was trying something in this spirit:

```
(World.town ^|-> Town.houses ^|-> index((x, y)) ^|-> House.presentsDelivered)
  .modify { _ + 1 }(world)
```

Which is syntactically wrong, but I think it's apparent what I wanted to do (modify `presentsDelivered` of `House` at specified `x, y` coordinates). So my question is, **how to modify the `index` part to access the map**?

Any help, clue or noob-friendly learning materials tips are welcome.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of documentation, we are slowly working on it. Please don't hesitate to pop up to monocle gitter, ask question here or on github.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're literally one character (and maybe an import) away from the solution:

```
import monocle.function.all.index
import monocle.std.map._

(
  World.town              ^|->
  Town.houses             ^|-?
  index((0, 0))           ^|->
  House.presentsDelivered
).modify(_ + 1)
```

Note that I've replaced the `^|->` immediately preceding the index with `^|-?`. This is necessary because `index((x, y))` is fundamentally different from `World.town` and the other macro-generated lenses for case class members. Those *can't not* point to a value, while `index` can fail if there's no value at the given index in the map. In terms of Monocle's types, `index((x, y))` is an `Optional[Houses, House]`, while `World.town` is a `Lens[World, Town]`.

Optionals are weaker in a sense than lenses, and once you've composed a lens with an optional, you're going to continue to have optionals even if you compose more lenses. So the following is a lens:

```
World.town ^|-> Town.houses
```

But this is an optional:

```
World.town ^|-> Town.houses ^|-? index((0, 0)) ^|-> House.presentsDelivered
```

Monocle consistently uses `x ^|-> y` to compose different types of `x` (lenses, optionals, traversals, etc.) with lenses, and `x ^|-? y` to compose different `x`s with optionals. I personally find the operators a little confusing and prefer `composeLens`, `composeOptional`, etc., but tastes vary, and if you want to memorize the operators you can at least be confident that they're used consistently—you just need to know which one you need for a given type.

The other potential issue with your code is that you can't just write this:

```
import monocle.function.all.index

val houses: monocle.Optional[Houses, House] = index((0, 0))
```

This won't compile on its own because `index` requires an instance of the `Index` type class for the type that it's indexing into (in this case `Map[(Int, Int), House]`. Monocle provides a generic instance for maps that will work, but you have to import it:

```
import monocle.std.map._
```

I'm afraid I don't have any terribly good suggestions for learning materials, but you can always ask questions here, and the [Monocle Gitter channel](https://gitter.im/julien-truffaut/Monocle) is fairly active.

Comment: Thank you for a thorough and correct answer. To be honest, I wasn't too optimistic about getting an answer - not sure how popular Monocle library is, but tag [tag:monocle-scala] wasn't even in double digits. I'm glad I was wrong, tomorrow I'm gonna have some fun solving those [Christmas puzzles](http://adventofcode.com/) :).